# How to hide tab selectors in tab control in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Basically i'm currently trying to create an ordering program in visual basic for an assignment and i want to know if it's possible to hide the tab controls at the top of the page and instead have users change tabs by pressing a button. I already know how to create buttons that change the page but i can't figure out how to hide the tab selectors.

An example of this would be after a user enters their details they would click next and then it would take them to the payment screen.

Please bear in mind i'm an absolute beginner so i may need a bit extra explaination

Comment: Old winforms trick: set `TabControl.Alignment = Right`. Then set `Width` of the `Form` to hide a headers of ``TabPages`

Comment: Popular options: 1) hide them, by putting them off the edge of the screen, or 2) put a blank picture/text/label control over the words.  3) Use a different control, like panels or groupboxes.  Do any of these seem like reasonable options?

Comment: @tgolisch : 4) Actually hide them? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom control where you override [**`WndProc`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc(v=vs.110).aspx) and trap the [**`TCM_ADJUSTRECT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760573(v=vs.85).aspx) message:

```
Public Class CustomTabControl
    Inherits TabControl

    Const TCM_ADJUSTRECT As Integer = &H1328

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef message As Message)
        If DesignMode = False AndAlso message.Msg = TCM_ADJUSTRECT Then
            message.Result = New IntPtr(1) 'Always return 1.
            Return
        End If

        MyBase.WndProc(message)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Build your project via the `Build > Build <your project name here>` menu, then you will be able to add it from the Tool Box.

Answer (score 0):

This is the dumest way to do it but it works:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load_2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim pic As New PictureBox
    pic.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    pic.Width = TabControl1.Width
    pic.Height = 21
    pic.Location = TabControl1.Location
    Me.Controls.Add(pic)
    pic.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

This removes the up line of the TabControl. If you want it use:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load_2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim pic1 As New PictureBox
    Dim pic2 As New PictureBox
    pic1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    pic1.Width = TabControl1.Width
    pic1.Height = 21
    pic1.Location = TabControl1.Location
    Me.Controls.Add(pic1)
    pic1.BringToFront()
    pic2.BackColor = Color.Gray
    pic2.Width = TabControl1.Width - 2
    pic2.Height = 1
    pic2.Location = New Point(TabControl1.Location.X, TabControl1.Location.Y + 20)
    Me.Controls.Add(pic2)
    pic2.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

Replace the `TabControl1` with your tab control name.